# iPhone 7 missing Calendar app

Tags: calendar

I read that you can't delete the calendar icon. Mine is missing and not in a folder. I tried power cycle - no good. Resetting desktop icons changed everything. My Mail is now a screen icon and my messages moved to the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 10 Apple added the ability to "delete" their stock apps.

To restore them just search the App Store for the app and "reinstall" it from there.